# TypeScript not able to iterate associative array

Tags: arrays, typescript

I have a service which populates my associative array in typescript,

```
fun populateData(){
let tempArr;
tempArr = [];
this.service.get('Post', 1, 'true').subscribe(
        (response) => {
          this.loadingIcon = false;

          for (let i = 0; i < response.results.length; i++) {
             tempList = response.results[i]['tags'];
             for ( let iter of tempList){
               if ( iter in tempArr) {
                 tempArr[iter] = tempArr[iter] + 1;
               }else {
                 tempArr[iter] = 1;
               }
             }
          }
        },
        (error) => {
          if (error['status'] === 401) {
            localStorage.clear();
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
          } else {
            this.router.navigateByUrl('/error');
          }
        }
      );
      console.log(tempArr);
        /*
          This function is inside a class, once I iterate get access to tempArr I will be assigning the tempArr data to a class variable like

       for (items in tempArr){
            this.data.push(items, tempArr[items]);
       }
        */
}
```

I'm able to populate my associative array with the service above which gives the following output in console,

[image: tempArr in the console log output]

I'm not able to iterate through this array, I tried a couple of methods like the following,

```
for ( const key in tempArr) {
      console.log(key + ':' + tempArr[key]);
    }
```

I want both they key and values from the array.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an object? They're made for this exact purpose.

Comment: @Gustorn I'm not sure of how to use object for this, any pointers will be of great help.

Comment: I'd have to see how `tempArr` is constructed

Comment: @Gustorn I've updated the question, with the tempArr declarations

Comment: you are not using `array` but rather plain object, and to iterate through all pairs of (key, value) you can use ES7 `Object.entries` method.

Answer (score 3):

TypeScript generally assumes that the keys to arrays are numbers. What you were doing might work but it's not very idiomatic. I'm not going to rewrite your whole function but here are a few pointers:

When constructing your associative array (map for short from now on) you should try using an object instead of an array:

```
const tagCounts: { [key: string]: number } = {};
for (const result of response.results) {
    for (const tag of result.tags) {
        tagCounts[tag] = (tagCounts[tag] || 0) + 1;
    }
}
```

Then you can iterate the result with:

```
for (const tag of Object.keys(tagCounts)) {
    const count = tagCounts[tag];
    // Other stuff here
}
```

Or if you have polyfills for `Object.entries` then with:

```
for (const [tag, count] of Object.entries(tagCounts)) {
    // Other stuff here
}
```

Looking at your code, `this.data.push` also seems wrong: it will add a string and a number to your `data` array which is almost certainly not what you want. You might want to consider converting `data` to an object as well if you want to store key-value pairs.

Comment: I tried this one, however while trying to iterate using Object.keys(tagCounts) it is not entering the for loop. I can see the data in the tagCounts object in console log, i tired printing Object.keys(tagCounts) which is printing an empty array of size zero.